# Not able to suspend Bosh VMs before putting laptop to sleep mode

Tags: cloud-foundry, cf-bosh

I am trying to install cloud foundry on a virtualbox using BOSH on my laptop. I am pretty new to this and trying to test it out.
I was able to deploy CF. However, my laptop went in to sleep mode and all the VMs went unresponsive. 
As per https://github.com/cloudfoundry/bosh-lite, the recommended guide for installing bosh doesn't need vagrant installation.
I am wondering if I still need to install vagrant and use vagrant suspend to put the VMs that BOSH manages on suspend mode to retain the cf routes and not having all the VMs go in unresponsive state.

Comment: Because you are using virtualbox, I assuming you are using an older version of cf. So, this article may work - http://rickfarmer.com/cloud-foundry-stop-and-start/

Comment: I suggest you switch to https://github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/cfdev